# How can I reach the last Zip file in a long row of nested Zip files

Tags: linux, terminal, zip, unzip

I have a task to reach the last file in long row of nested Zip archives. They go like this:

```
3301.zip
       |
       3300.zip
              |
              3299.zip
                     |
                      ...
                         |
                         1.zip
```

Basically, I have to extract one archive from another 3300 times in order to reach the file within `1.zip`.

I have searched for ways to do this, but maybe my search terms weren't right or I missed something. I tried "reach last file nested zips", "extract nested zips". My working environment is Linux and I tried several Terminal commands. Nothing did what I wanted.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment. But assuming good faith look here at this post on the [Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14125/30848). I assume you might be able to create a huge string with something like `{3301..1}` and then unzip that. This big trick here seems to be the numbers are sequential. Start from there and find a solution. Maybe make your life easier by trying the concept with 1 to 3 nested Zip files and if that works? Try it on the big file.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried to do something like this as a test and can’t get it to work. But it expresses the ideas I posted in a previous comment: `unzip -p $(echo {3..1} | tr " " "/").zip;`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the zip files (until after reaching the last one) recursively using a `while` command:

```
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
```

This while run again and again looking for a zip file in this directory, and extract the zip file if found, while removing the parent zip file. And it will do so over and over again until it does so for the last zip file (1.zip) and can't find any more zip files.